# Cделать функцию this.click стрелочной

Tags: javascript, функции, this

````
  this.element = buttonElement;
  this.message = message;
  this.click = function () {
    console.log(this.message);
  };
}

const button = new Button(document.querySelector('.btn'), 'Меня нажали');

button.element.addEventListener('click', button.click ); ```
````

Comment: ознакомьтесь со всеми пунктами https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/asking    и особенно https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы из обычной функции получить стрелочную, необходимо убрать слово `function` и добавить саму стрелочку

```
this.click = function () {
```

переходит в

```
this.click = () => {
```